# django get files from different directories [NOT CONFIRMED]

Tags: python, django, readfile

I have a django app (installed on a Debian server) where there is file upload.

Traditionaly, it ulpload in a folder in site_media. 
For some reason,(please don't ask why,take it for granted) I have to save the files in a different disk.

The path to the other disk is /disk/site_media
The saving do the other disk is donw succesfully!
When I try to open the file by clicking on it , I get File not Found.

**I am open to ideas!!!**

Here's my code when uploading the file:

```
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user_id = self.request.user.pk
        obj.save()
        initial_path = obj.file.path
        print(initial_path)
        new = settings.MEDIA_ROOT_NEW + obj.file.name
        print(new)
        #os.rename(initial_path,new)
        shutil.move(initial_path, new)
```

I upload the files in my EmployeeDoc class:

```
      class EmployeeDoc(models.Model):

           file = models.FileField('DocFile', upload_to='edocs/')
           employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee , related_name='documents')
           user = models.ForeignKey(User , related_name='employeedocs')
           created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,default=timezone.now)
           update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,default=timezone.now)
```

I get the files in my template with a function written under my Employee class:

```
   class Employee(models.Model):
         name ... 
         last ...

     def getDocuments(self):
         return EmployeeDoc.objects.filter(employee_id=self.pk,del_f=0)
```

Here are my paths in settings.py:

```
 MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'site_media/')
 MEDIA_ROOT_NEW = '/disk/site_media/'
 MEDIA_URL = '/site_media/'
```

In my urls.py despite all the othe urls I have:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're serving `MEDIA_ROOT` directory on `MEDIA_URL` url. That means files from `MEDIA_ROOT_NEW` won't be accessible on `MEDIA_URL` url.

If you want to serve all your media files from `MEDIA_ROOT_NEW`, change line:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

to

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT_NEW)
```

If you want to serve both directories on one URL, consider using nginx or other web server for that.

Comment: Your answer is correct, I knew that already! 
At the end I decided to go for larger disk. Didn't have the luxury to play games with nginx! 
Thank you for your time!!